# How do I fetch information (an account name) from a save file (N:\userFile) on Python

Tags: python, save

I have created a banking ATM machine for a school computing project, so I am novice at coding in Python. I have created a piece of code that saves a User's name and PIN code, but I dont know how to get the programme to remember the name and link it with the paired PIN code.

```
balance_user = 500
balance_new = 0
print "Welcome to the Banking Bank PLC public ATM service"
user = raw_input("Please enter your ATM account name and insert your Banking Card. If you do not have an ATM account, please insert your Banking Card and enter New_User.")
if user == "New_User":
    print "Weclome to the Banking Bank PLC ATM service."
    user = raw_input ("Please enter an ATM account name that you wish to use to log onto the Banking Bank ATMs")

    f1 =open('N:\userFile', 'a+')
    print >> f1,user


    print "Welcome", user, "to the Banking Bank PLC ATM service."

    PIN = raw_input ("Please asign a P.I.N to this ATM account. 4 Numbers, no letters or symbols.")

    f1 =open('N:\userFile', 'a+')
    print >> f1, PIN


    print PIN, ", do not forget this number."
    print "Please log back into the ATM, using you new ATM account name and P.I.N"
```

That is the code, and it saves to a text file. The data is all there, so if the User writes `"BOB"` as their name and `"9999"` as their PIN, the save would say `"BOB 9999"`. How do I fetch this information back, so when they log on again the bank ATM remembers who they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has great documentation on how to write/read files, with good few examples. [See here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

It seems like you will need something like this:

```
f = open('N:\userFile', 'r')
for line in f:
        # process line
        print line
f.close()
```